# jquery ui: Collision detection of draggable element with relocation/ resizing of other element having collision

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision, drag

```
  var overlaps = (function () {
            function getPositions(elem) {
                var pos, width, height;
                pos = jQueryEasyUI(elem).position();
                width = jQueryEasyUI(elem).width();
                height = jQueryEasyUI(elem).height();
                return [[pos.left, pos.left + width], [pos.top, pos.top + height]];
            }

            function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
                var r1, r2;
                r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
                r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
                return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
            }

            return function (a, b) {
                var pos1 = getPositions(a),
                    pos2 = getPositions(b);
                return comparePositions(pos1[0], pos2[0]) && comparePositions(pos1[1], pos2[1]);
            };
        })();
```

I saw above code somewhere on stackoverflow to detect the collision between two dragging objects. 
But my problem is far beyond the detection of collision. I have few div's of fixed sizes in a droppable regions I drags one of the div over other div. Then there occurs following scenario:

1. I drops the div on other div
2. Drops the div beside another
3. Drops the div such that the droppable is just covering the one part of other div.

This is visible from the given image diagram.

[image]

[image]

The red rectangle is droppable. Now when the red rectangle is dropped the following thing shall happen.

1. If the red rectangle is dropped from side (left / right) black rectangle shall shrink in size to accommodate for size of the dropped element. It shall happen in to all the elements whether they are covered partially.
2. Now if it is dropped from above then, the covered elements shall be moved below.

Please help!

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this? Maybe add `jquery-ui` tag. I would also provide a working example of what you have tried thus far.

Comment: yes, i am still looking for answer.

Comment: Okay, do you have a fiddle or plnk of what you have tried so far? what is not working so far?

Comment: Did you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/48ks48Ld/7/

Comment: @Twisty I see that you have applied a left to right transition. yes, this is what I want. I would have to improve it a bit. I will come to you back for further discussion